# MDAPI retrieve of Flow from Packaging Org (1GP) has unexpected namespaced field

Tags: managed-package, process-builder, mdapi

Given a trivial process builder decision block formula on the package's namespaced object:

```
[mynamespace__Foo__c].mynamespace__Amount > 1000
```

Retrieving a Process Builder (via MDAPI) with source from a long-standing packaging org's name-spaced 1GP (for purposes of adding to VCS), I get the following XML:

```
<formulas>
<processMetadataValues>
  <name>originalFormula</name>
  <value>
    <stringValue>[mynamespace__Foo__c].mynamespace__Amount__c &gt; 1000</stringValue>
  </value>
</processMetadataValues>
<name>formula_myRule_1</name>
<dataType>Boolean</dataType>
<expression>{!myVariable_current.mynamespace__Amount__c} &gt; 1000</expression>
```

Target of the deployment was GitHub, the `Flow` was subsequently deployed to a scratch org namespaced as `mynamespace`

When I compared the scratch org's Flow metadata back to the GitHub branch, they were different. Specifically, the `<expression>` element:

- `GitHub:       <expression>{!myVariable_current.mynamespace__Amount__c} &gt; 1000</expression>`
- `Scratch org:  <expression>{!myVariable_current.Amount__c} &gt; 1000</expression>`

Note the distinction in the way the `Amount` field is referenced; GitHub (from original MDAPI retrieve) has it namespaced; scratch org does not.

I tried to replicate this by creating a brand new 1GP (following this [1GP Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/first_generation_managed_packages)) but this time, when I retrieved from the spanking new 1GP managed package, the `Flow` XML did not namespace the field in `<expression>`:

- `GitHub:      <expression>{!myVariable_current.Amount__c} &gt; 1000</expression>`
- `Scratch org: <expression>{!myVariable_current.Amount__c} &gt; 1000</expression>`

### What's Going On?

- In both tests, the managed package was in **Managed - Released** State
- The only thing I can think of is that the Flow metadata in the legacy 1GP is an older form that when deployed to a new org has the field's namespace stripped when building the `<expression>`.

There is an obvious workaround (not starting by going from the 1GP directly to VCS but instead ensuring that the XML is "current" by retrieving - pushing to scratch Org - then pulling back to a project before pushing to VCS).