# Packaging org removes Namespace prefix from element references of packaged Flows

Tags: visual-workflow, managed-package, metadata, namespace

We're developing a 1st generation managed package that includes Flows triggered by a Custom Object insertion.
Previously we've been using Ant Migration Tool to deploy/retrieve metadata to our Packaging Org.
Recently we've upgraded to sfdx CLI and bumped API version 49.0 to 54.0. After retrieving package metadata, we saw a diff in our packaged flows: our Namespace Prefix has been removed from all element references.
I.e. `!$Record.Namespace__CustomField__c` became `!$Record.CustomField__c`
Minor detail, for whatever reason it kept just a single occurrence of a reference appearing in `leftValueReference` context: `<leftValueReference>$Record.Namespace__CustomField__c</leftValueReference>`

After deploying this metadata back to the org our Flows of course are broken because of the unknown references, and any tests triggering the Flows fail.
After adding the Namespace Prefix back in manually and re-deploying, the problem gets fixed and the Flows are fully functional again.

Why is this happening and is there a fix? Has there been a breaking change in any of the recent API versions?

Comment: This unanswered question from 2y ago seems to describe similar problem https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/308587/mdapi-retrieve-of-flow-from-packaging-org-1gp-has-unexpected-namespaced-field